# como puedo refactorizar estos metodos en java?

Tags: java, poo, refactoring

como puedo refactorizar estos dos metodos

```
public void iniciar1()
{
    int numeroCasos = 0; 
    int numeroDigitos = 0; 
    int digitosConsecutivos = 0;
    int resultado = 0;
    int validar = 0;

    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);

    numeroCasos = leer.nextInt();

    if(numeroCasos<=100)
    {
        String datosNK[] = new String[numeroCasos];
        String numero[] = new String[numeroCasos];

        for (int i = 0; i < numeroCasos; i++) 
        {
            String saltoDeLinea = leer.nextLine();
            datosNK[i] = leer.nextLine();

            String[] partes1 = datosNK[i].split(" ");

            numeroDigitos = Integer.parseInt(partes1[0]);
            digitosConsecutivos = Integer.parseInt(partes1[1]);

            if(digitosConsecutivos<=7 && numeroDigitos<=1000)
            {
                validar = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                validar = 0;
                break;
            }

            numero[i] = leer.next();
        }

        if(validar==1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < numeroCasos; i++)
            {
                String[] partes2 = datosNK[i].split(" ");

                numeroDigitos = Integer.parseInt(partes2[0]);
                digitosConsecutivos = Integer.parseInt(partes2[1]);

                resultado =  getProductoMayor(numero[i],digitosConsecutivos);
            }
        }
    }

}

public void iniciar2()
{
    int numeroCasos = 0;

    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);

    numeroCasos = leer.nextInt();

    int numero[] = new int [numeroCasos];

    for (int i = 0; i < numeroCasos; i++)
    {
         numero[i] = leer.nextInt();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numeroCasos; i++) 
    {
        System.out.println(getPalindromoMayor(numero[i]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola.. refactorizar para lograr que? cuando publicas una revisión de código, necesitamos saber que queres mejorar.

Comment: hacerlos mas simplificados  los codigos porque estan muy grandes los metodo

Comment: Explica a que llamas muy grande. Estos metodos son re chiquitos. Ademas grnades en que? En cantidad de lineas? Eso no deberia molestar a nadie.

Comment: Al parecer no puede resolverlo que lastima